# Transforming SUMIFS to individual cell references

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new here, so apologies if this has been answered before.

I am trying to create a VBA script to transform cells using SUMIFS to pull data to individual cell references.

Ie. if I pull a value from another tab using a SUMIFS function, I want the output to be exactly the cell it is referenced (=cell).

Specifically, I am thinking of:

1. Read all cells in a sheet,
2. Identify which cells pull value with a SUMIFS function
3. Get the cell reference from which the data matching the SUMIFS is sourced
4. Convert the SUMIFS formula to the matching cell reference (ie. =A35)

I am trying to see individual codes for this, but not sure where to begin with, or if this has been previously solved.

Any thoughts will be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Tried the above steps

Comment: So just use the constraints that are used in the sumifs().

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). you should add what have you tried. Also, ¿are you sre your SUMIF is getting the result from just ONE cell?